# How to add alternate text to pictures displayed by clicking on buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add separate alternate text (such as "picture 1/2 not available") in case a picture fails to display? How can I change this code to allow that to happen?

(Sridhar's code)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function pic1()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "picture 1 source";
        }
        function pic2()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src ="picture 2 source";
        } 
</script>

<img src = "" id = "img"/> <input type="button" value="Show Picture
    1" onclick="pic1()"/> <input type="button" value="Show Picture 2"
    onclick="pic2()"/>
```

Comment: Sure, look into the onload and onerror (or onfail - I forget) methods of the image element. You can assign an alt text, attempt to load the image. If the load fails, you can change the alt text to indicate the failure.

Comment: Hey! Please consider letting me know whether my answer worked or not :) thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to add separate alternate text (such as "picture 1/2
>   not available") in case a picture fails to display?

Yes, that is what the `alt` attribute is for - it is actually a required attribute for images anyway.

You can just set the alt tag of an image using `.alt` like so:

```
var image = document.getElementById("img");
image.src = "Image src here"
image.alt = "Image alt here - if image failed to render, you will see this!"
```

Assuming  you have to do it by JavaScript. Most people simply just include it in the HTML itself:

```
<img src = "" id = "img" alt="Alternative text here!"/>
```

See more about the `alt` attribute [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-alt).

---

**Edit:** You could look into using `onerror` in regard to Derek's point:

> "onerror allows for different alt text when an image is simply not found
>   rendered or when the image is not found"

Comment: Yes, he should be using `alt`, but that covers all instances when an image isn't displayed.  Of course, a sighted user will know that the alt text is showing because he sees a broken image and alt text, but a visually-impaired user gets the same alt text whether or not the image is found. `onerror` allows for different alt text when an image is simply not rendered or when the image is not found.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way.  Use the `onerror` attribute with the error text or a path to an alternate image.

```
<img onerror="this.src='/path/to/alternate/img.jpg'" src="/your/img.jpg">
```

or

```
<img onerror="this.alt='picture 1/2 not available'" src="/your/img.jpg">
```

**Edit:**  Of course, you should be using the (required) `alt` attribute on every image, as Zenith points out.  Use of `onerror` assumes you wanted to show the user something different if the image could not be found instead of, say, the user is using a screen reader or has otherwise chosen to disable images.  One alternative is to show the original `alt` text with the 'not available' message appended:

```
<img alt="picture 1/2" onerror="this.alt=this.alt+': not available'" src="/your/img.jpg">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxRgK/)

Comment: I wanted to add, of course, that the alt attribute should have more descriptive information than simply "picture 1/2," as its purpose is to aid visually-impaired users.